# Importing Data from CSV to PSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

I am trying to import data from a CSV to a PSQL database. I found a good example of how to copy the data from the csv on stack overflow, which looks like the following (only the file path is different).

```
\COPY manjadata FROM '/filepath/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

However, this is breaking on the first line, giving me the error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "address"
CONTEXT:  COPY data, line 1, column id: "address"
```

My table is set up as follows:

```
class Data < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :data do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.integer :zip
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The CSV looks like the following:

```
address,city,state,zip,name,url
211 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Mother Anna's,http://motheranna.com/
226 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Lucca,http://www.luccaboston.com/
227 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Cobblestone,http://www.CobblestoneNe.com
```

How can I import this csv into the psql database without it breaking? I've looked up a lot of docs and the error message, but haven't found a fix for my problem yet.

THANKS!

Comment: What happens when you give like this `COPY manjadata FROM '/filepath/data.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',');`?

Comment: If I don't have the backslash before copy as in `\COPY` I get the error message ` could not open file "...filepath..." for reading: Permission denied`. If I add the `\COPY` I get the error message `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "address"
CONTEXT:  COPY data, line 1, column id: "address"`

Comment: Where do you find that syntax? I've seen a lot many in the SO,all are without backslash before COPY.

Comment: And you have to specify the headers with `HEADERS true` in the command.

Comment: @Pavan it breaks even if I remove the headers. The backslash I found when looking up error message `could not open file "...filepath..." for reading: Permission denied`

Comment: Can you try to run this command \COPY data(address,city,state,zip,name) FROM 'path/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just importing the data with a seed file as follows:

Inside of `seeds.rb`:

```
require 'csv'

datafile = Rails.root + 'db/data.csv'

CSV.foreach(datafile, headers: true) do |row|

  Data.find_or_create_by({address: row[0]}) do |hr|
    hr.address = row[0]
    hr.city =  row[1]
    hr.state =  row[2]
    hr.zip =  row[3]
    hr.name =  row[4]
  end

end
```

Then I simply placed my `data.csv` into the `db` folder with the CSV in the same format (as follows):

```
address,city,state,zip,name
211 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Mother Anna's,http://motheranna.com/
226 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Lucca,http://www.luccaboston.com/
227 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Cobblestone,http://www.CobblestoneNe.com
```

Finally, I ran `rake db:seed`, and the database is filled with the data that I need :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run below command to import your data using below CSV

```
address,city,state,zip,name
211 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Mother Anna's
226 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Lucca
227 Hanover St,Boston,MA,2113,Cobblestone
```

Command

```
 \COPY data(address,city,state,zip,name) FROM 'path/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header;
```

Please note that url is removed from CSV as it is not present in database